# Suddenly all virtual envs fail

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, jupyter

I use vscode and I'm working with Jupyter in this particular example.  Yesterday, I was doing my work fine. Today, my venv is broken, so I deleted and started again:

```
python -m venv venv
./venv/Scripts/Activate
```

Okay, so I have brand new venv now.  So lets try updating pip:

```
python -m pip --upgrade pip
```

And I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jmarshall\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\jmarshall\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\jmarshall\source\mdgattribution\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "C:\Users\jmarshall\source\mdgattribution\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "C:\Users\jmarshall\source\mdgattribution\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Users\jmarshall\source\mdgattribution\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .exceptions import (
  File "C:\Users\jmarshall\source\mdgattribution\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\exceptions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.http_client import (
  File "C:\Users\jmarshall\source\mdgattribution\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 203, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "C:\Users\jmarshall\source\mdgattribution\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "C:\Users\jmarshall\source\mdgattribution\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\jmarshall\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.parser'
```

Okay, lets try to ignore this an set up jupyter.

```
pip install wheel
pip install juypterlab
pip install ipykernel
```

Then when I try running a cell in that notebook in VSCode I get this error:

```
Kernel died (code: 1). ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.parser', 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jmarshall\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\jmarshall\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\jmarshall\source\mdgattribution\venv\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "c:\Users\jmarshall\source\mdgattribution\venv\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 22, in <module>
    from IPython.core.application import (
  File "c:\Users\jmarshall\source\mdgattribution\venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "c:\Users\jmarshall\source\mdgattribution\venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\embed.py", line 17, in <module>
    from IPython.terminal.ipapp import load_default_config
  File "c:\Users\jmarshall\source\mdgattribution\venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 28, in <module>
    from IPython.core.magics import (
  File "c:\Users\jmarshall\source\mdgattribution\venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .code import CodeMagics, MacroToEdit
  File "c:\Users\jmarshall\source\mdgattribution\venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\code.py", line 23, in <module>
    from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
  File "C:\Users\jmarshall\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "C:\Users\jmarshall\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.parser'
```

What the heck is going on here?

***Edit1***

I've just proven it will error on the 3.8 global interpreter instance, even though I have other notebooks working on that. I've added a screenshot of the project.

[image]

Comment: can you show me the file structure of your project?

Comment: @algorythms - I added a ss that shows you the structure, but I've just actually figured out this happens on the global interpreter instance as well.

Answer (score 1):

You created a package named `email`, you need to rename it to some other names.